# Bookmarklet to save file

Tags: firefox, bookmarklet

Is is possible to use a bookmarklet in Firefox to save/open a file directly?

Many bookmarklets open a page on which one can click on a link to download the result. E.g. using a blob link. Is it possible to avoid this extra click and invoke the "save file" / "open file" dialog directly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To trigger the "Save As" dialog for any resource (`blob:`, `http:`, whatever permitted scheme), use the [`download` attribute](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/links.html#downloading-resources) of an anchor. This is supported since Firefox 20.

Example: A bookmarklet that presents the current page as a download:

```
javascript:(function() {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = location.href;
    a.download = 'filename.html';
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    a.parentNode.removeChild(a);
})();
```

To trigger the `Open` dialog, create an `<input type="file">`, and `click()` it. For many examples, see [Using files from web applications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications).

Comment: For what it's worth, here in 2023 this did not work for me, when trying to download an .mp3 file. Instead, Firefox just opened the file in that tab, with a media "play" button. Easy enough to "Ctrl+S" from there, but did not open the "Save As..." dialog directly, as promised.

Answer (score 0):

Should be possible if the bookmarklet sends you to a page where the web server sends the appropriate headers to force a download. Example:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.zip"
Content-Type: application/zip
```