# Function runs on parent window instead of child

Tags: javascript, debugging, createelement

This runs as a bookmarklet.

The creation of windows, extracting of values, and writing them to window "log" works perfect.

I want to save the contents of "log" window to scrypt.txt, but the contents of the parent window get saved instead. What did I do wrong?

```
javascript:
setInterval(logging,60000);
w1 = window.open("https://scrypt.cc/index.php");
log = window.open("");

function logging(){
    if(w1.document.body.innerHTML == 'Server is currently busy. Please try again later.'){
        w1.location.href = 'https://scrypt.cc/index.php';
        console.log("busy");
    }else{
        console.log("ok");
        log.document.body.innerHTML = '';
        var re=/var\s*dayprofitperkhs\s*=\s*([0-9\.]+)\s/gi;
        var matches=re.exec(w1.document.body.innerHTML);
        log.document.write(RegExp.$1 + "<p></p>");
        log.document.write(w1.$('#t9_2').val() + "<p></p>");
        log.setTimeout(save,1000);
        w1.location.href = 'https://scrypt.cc/index.php';
    }
}
function save() {
    a = log.document.createElement('a');
    a.href = log.location.href;
    a.download = 'scrypt.txt';
    log.document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    a.parentNode.removeChild(a);
}
```

Edit: Saving as *.html, with another a.href works perfectly:

```
a.href = 'data:text/html;base64,' + btoa(log.document.body.outerHTML);
a.download = 'values.html';
```

Comment: Because of same-origin protections, unless your main window is also from `https://scrypt.cc`, you cannot access the contents of the `https://scrypt.cc/index.php` window.

Comment: I run the bookmarklet from that site, so it basically opens itself in w1, just to be able to refresh it. Getting those values in yet another window works perfectly, but it's the saving of that window that doesn't work, it saves the main window.

Comment: Did you try to add the `a` element to w1's document instead o the parent window's document?

Comment: @Prusse: how would I do that?

Comment: The `log.document.body.appendChild(a);` part =)

Comment: I suck at this :) w1 and main window are exactly the same url though, so that wouldn't do much good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a working solution:

```
javascript:
setInterval(logging,60000);
w1 = window.open("https://scrypt.cc/index.php");
log = window.open("");

function logging(){
    if(w1.document.body.innerHTML == 'Server is currently busy. Please try again later.'){
        w1.location.href = 'https://scrypt.cc/index.php';
        console.log("server busy");
    }else{
        log.document.body.innerHTML = '';
        var re=/var\s*dayprofitperkhs\s*=\s*([0-9\.]+)\s/gi;
        var matches=re.exec(w1.document.body.innerHTML);
        log.document.write("<p>" + RegExp.$1 + "</p>");
        log.document.write("<p>" + w1.$('#t9_2').val() + "</p>");
        log.setTimeout(save,1000);
        w1.location.href = 'https://scrypt.cc/index.php';
    }
}
function save() {
    console.log("file saved");
    a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = 'data:text/html;base64,' + btoa(log.document.body.outerHTML);
    a.download = 'values.html';
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    a.parentNode.removeChild(a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `save()` function is using the `document` of your main window.  If you want it to run in the `log()` context, then you need to use `log.document` and `log.location`.

```
function save() {
    a = log.document.createElement('a');
    a.href = log.location.href;
    a.download = 'scrypt.txt';
    log.document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    a.parentNode.removeChild(a);
}
```

This is just a guess, but you could try moving all the saving code into a script tag in the log window like this:

```
setInterval(logging, 60000);
var w1 = window.open("https://scrypt.cc/index.php");
var log = window.open("");

function logging() {
    if (w1.document.body.innerHTML == 'Server is currently busy. Please try again later.') {
        w1.location.href = 'https://scrypt.cc/index.php';
        console.log("busy");
    } else {
        console.log("ok");
        log.document.body.innerHTML = '';
        var re = /var\s*dayprofitperkhs\s*=\s*([0-9\.]+)\s/gi;
        var matches = re.exec(w1.document.body.innerHTML);
        log.document.write(RegExp.$1 + "<p></p>");
        log.document.write(w1.$('#t9_2').val() + "<p></p>");

        // insert script tag to create the save link and click it
        var sc = "<scr" + "ipt>";
        sc += "function save() {";
        sc += "var a = document.createElement('a');";
        sc += "a.href = location.href;";
        sc += "a.download = 'scrypt.txt';";
        sc += "document.body.appendChild(a);";
        sc += "a.click();";
        sc += "a.parentNode.removeChild(a);";
        sc += "}";
        sc += "setTimeout(save, 1000);";
        sc += "</scr" + "ipt>";
        log.document.write(sc);

        w1.location.href = 'https://scrypt.cc/index.php';
    }
}
```

Comment: Same result... content of parent window gets grabbed

Comment: @WannesDemaeght - Does the right content get into the log window?  If so, then the issue is with your download operation which you don't really disclose.  Also, please show the fixed `save()` function so we can see if you fixed it correctly.

Comment: Right content gets displayed in the 'log()' window, sorry if that was not clear. I'll update with fixed 'save()' function. What do you mean when you say that I don't really disclose the download operation? 'save()' IS the download operation...

Comment: @WannesDemaeght - what does the `.click()` operation actually do in `save()`.  Presumably, that's how the window gets saved.  But, we can't see any of that code.

Comment: @WannesDemaeght - you're missing `log.document.body.appendChild(a);`

Comment: I have no idea, I got that code from here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17900671/bookmarklet-to-save-file)

Comment: sorry, forgot to edit that line in. Was in the code I tested however, still the same result...

Comment: @WannesDemaeght - Just a wild guess, but perhaps you have to insert code into the log window to run the `.click()` from its own code.

Comment: There is no such code in main window either... doesn't the click() reference to the element created, being a? and as that element is being created in log, it should work? I'm just trying to better understand this...

Comment: @WannesDemaeght - The issue is that SaveAs thinks it applies to your parent window not the log window regardless of where the link was.  I'm just guessing that the context of the click is the wrong window because the code that issued the click was run from the main window so that's the window that the SaveAs command runs in.  If you inserted a `<script>` tag into the log window and the code in that script tag is what found the right link and then clicked it, the only context that could run in would be the log window itself.

Comment: Could you please provide a working proof of concept? I'd be willing to pay for your time.

Comment: @WannesDemaeght - I took one more guess at something to try (added to my answer).

Comment: @WannesDemaeght - did you get this figured out?  If so, care to accept my answer (click the green checkmark to the left of the answer) to indicate to the community that you got an answer and to earn yourself some reputation points?

Comment: I'll update the original question with a working solution. Thanks for trying to help, but that last solution you posted didn't work either.

Comment: @WannesDemaeght - you are not supposed to update the question with your solution here on StackOverflow.  Instead, you can post an answer to your own question.